# Better method of viewing "adb bugreport" output? `

Tags: android

Is there a better method of getting detailed information about an android phone than running "adb bugreport"? Running it produces a wall of text that could take an hour to sift through. Are there any desktop UI applications or Eclipse views that can can allow you to browse all this info?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out [ChkBugReport](https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/ChkBugReport/wiki), an open source tool written by Sony Developers.

Github link to source code is [here](https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/ChkBugReport)

Comment: Took some minutes to find the .jar file: https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/ChkBugReport/wiki/Where-to-obtain-it

Comment: fail to convert the bugreport

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/) with my Android applications.  It allows you to send detailed information about application crashes to your BugSense Dashboard.  The reports contain OS information, device information, information about whether the user was connected to WiFi, Data, if GPS is turned on, a stack trace of the exception, and really nice graphs that show you various issues.  The issue some might have about this is that it sends the crash information without any user input, so it might be something to prompt the user about before sending.

As far as using things in Eclipse [the DDMS tool may  help](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html).  It's built into the debug view in Eclipse if you have the ADT Plugin.  If you'd rather not use it with Eclipse, it also comes installed by default in the Tools folder of your SDK path.

I'm not entirely sure the BugSense thing is what you're looking for, but I find it very useful.  Other than that, DDMS is really the best tool that I know about.  Hopefully you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you, though i'm more interested at the moment in debugging local crashes on my phone. I get random reboots, and rather than just wipe and reload the phone, I want to use this as an opportunity to explore the system a bit. Hence why I like the idea of seeing all the information bugreport can offer.